# PHP Curl not posting data, although it is receiving

Tags: php, forms, curl

I'm trying to make an API through PHP cURL and my client side (form submission) is receiving data from the API. It is just not posting it to the API.

```
$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type= application/json"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

// execute the request and store the return value.
$message = curl_exec($ch);

echo 'Message returned from API is:' .  $message;
```

This is the code to receive the message from the API. It is returning a message so hopefully no errors there.

This is the API code (below):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>The API</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

//date, job number, customer, worksite, duties performed, total hours spent, type of hours

$date = $_POST['date'];
$jobnumber = $_POST['jobnumber'];
$customer = $_POST['customer'];
$worksite = $_POST['worksite'];
$duties = $_POST['duties'];
$hours = $_POST['hours'];
$hourtype = $_POST['hourtype'];
$username = $_POST['username'];



$ok = true;
$error ;

//validate the inputs
if (empty($date)) {
    $ok = false;
    $error .= "Date field empty, ";
}

if (empty($jobnumber)) {
    $ok = false;
    $error .= "Job Number field empty, ";
}
if (empty($customer)) {
    $ok = false;
    $error .= "Customer field empty, ";
}

if (empty($worksite)) {
    $ok = false;
    $error .= "Worksite field empty, ";
}
if (empty($duties)) {
    $ok = false;
    $error .= "Duties field empty, ";
}
if (empty($hours)) {
    $ok = false;
    $error .= "Hours field empty, ";
}

if (empty($hourtype)) {
    $ok = false;
    $error .= "Hour type not specified, ";
}

$data = $date . ', ' . $jobnumber . ', ' . $customer . ', ' . $worksite . ', ' . $duties . ', ' . $hours . ', ' . $hourtype;
echo $data;
?>
</body>

</html>
```

My submit page is returning:

> "Message returned from API is: , , , , , ,"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your $data look like?

Comment: Tip: `CURLOPT_POST` is automatically added to the request when you set `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, based on this , `CURLOPT_POST` is unnecessary .

Comment: @Drakes $data returns ", , , , , ," It is passing the commas but not the data, so i've guessed its not posting the variables to the api.

Comment: Actually, I mean what is `$data` from `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);`? If you are passing an array, then you must do this instead: `http_build_query($data)`

Comment: @Drakes it is returning "Array". 

This is my code:

$data = array(
    'date' => $date,
    'jobnumber' => $jobnumber,
    'customer' => $customer,
    'worksite' => $worksite,
    'duties' => $duties,
    'hours' => $hours,
    'hourtype' => $hourtype,
    'username' => $username
 
);

Comment: That won't work. Try this instead: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));` and let me know how that works out

Comment: @Drakes IT WORKED. You are my saviour! Please explain why the use of the build query? For future reference.. Thank you so much!

Comment: Done. Please see my answer below. :)

Comment: You could use this class https://github.com/php-mod/curl is very useful to use CURL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be passing in an array to cURL.

```
$data = array( 'date' => $date, 'jobnumber' => $jobnumber, 'customer' => $customer, 'worksite' => $worksite, 'duties' => $duties, 'hours' => $hours, 'hourtype' => $hourtype, 'username' => $username );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Instead, build a query string for cURL to work with like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
```

The reason is because if you pass in an array, the `Content-type` header is automatically set to `multipart/form-data`, but you want `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so you can access the POSTed information through the global `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me somehow had this for the curl job:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    ...
));
```

See the arbitrary `Content-Type` header that I set for the POST, which is obviously not right. It's preventing curl to set the right `Content-Type` which should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Removed `'Content-Type: application/json'` and the destination URL was successfully receiving the POST data.